# Builder C++ Delete all sub node in TreeNode

Tags: c++builder, vcl

How to delete all sub node in the some treenode?

```
TTreeNode* ParentNode = TreeView->Selected;
int countNode = ParentNode->Count;
for(int p=0; p<countNode-1; p++)
{
    ParentNode->Item[p]->Delete();
}
```

this code dosn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call [`DeleteChildren`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TTreeNode.DeleteChildren) on the parent node:

```
ParentNode->DeleteChildren();
```

Comment: Thank you @David Heffernan.. I'm sorry for this easy question!

Comment: That's fine. No need to be sorry at all. It can be hard to find your way around all the tree view classes. It's a complex beast.

Answer (score 0):

David gave you the right answer (use `TTreeNode::DeleteChildren()`), but you should also understand why your original code was failing so you don't make the same mistake again later.

You were looping forwards from first child to last child, deleting each node as you went along.  Every time you deleted a child, the parent node's `Count` decremented but you did not update your `countNode` variable accordingly, and the index of each following child node decremented but you did not account for that when accessing `Item[p]`.

The *correct* way to write such a loop would look more like this instead:

```
TTreeNode* ParentNode = TreeView->Selected;
int countNode = ParentNode->Count;
for(int p = 0; p < countNode; ++p)
{
    ParentNode->Item[0]->Delete();
}
```

Or:

```
TTreeNode* ParentNode = TreeView->Selected;
int countNode = ParentNode->Count;
while (countNode > 0)
{
    ParentNode->Item[0]->Delete();
    --countNode;
}
```

Or:

```
TTreeNode* ParentNode = TreeView->Selected;
int countNode = ParentNode->Count;
for(int p = countNode-1; p >= 0; --p)
{
    ParentNode->Item[p]->Delete();
}
```

Comment: I fixed my issue with decrement loop.. but in my case, it's more performant to avoid the loop and I use DeleteChildren. Thx Remy. Thx David.

Comment: Would you need to delete the children, or would `Delete()` do that?